# Hive supports Nonequi join ?

Tags: hadoop, join, hive

As far as I know, Hive doesnt support `NonEqui join`. But in hive documention, they have mentioned `NonEqui join` is a valid join condition. Kindly refer the below screenshot and [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-JoinSyntax).

I am getting below Error when I tried NonEqui Join..

**FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 6:4 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN**

[image: Hive NonEqui Join]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive does not support inequality join it looks mistake in document .

SELECT a.* FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON (a.id **=** b.id)